Error (Xcode): Target debug_unpack_ios failed
Error Code
I am interested in app development so I watched a tutorial on how to install flutter on vsc. After  downloading the emulators and other requirements I tried to run the default code to see if the emulators would work. After a few seconds the ios emulator didn't change and a message popped up in my terminal with the error code. The andriod emulator works fine it is just the ios emulator.
